# Set search target to application server not front end

Tags: search, 2016

I configured a SharePoint 2016 farm

- 2 wfe with distributed cache
- 2 app with search

I configured the search service to work on the two app servers and the search topology shows the two servers

What I need  **when a user do a search it should not go to the load balancer then wfe, I need to perform crawl on the same both app servers**

I found some articles said create dns and set the host file entries but I don't know How? Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply,** Let your `SharePoint URL` point to `127.0.0.1` in `Hosts` file

**Example**

- Consider your SharePoint Portal URL is `https://qassas.com`
- So you just need to add a new entry in the `hosts` file on all SharePoint Servers as the following

  ```
  127.0.0.1     qassas.com
  ```

Comment: Thanks, For all SP servers or only app servers?

Comment: preferred all servers